# when calling the ListObjects operation: Missing required header for this request: x-amz-content-sha256

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to copy from one bucket to another bucket in aws with the below command

aws s3 cp s3://bucket1/media s3://bucket2/media --profile xyz --recursive

Returns an error saying

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the ListObjects operation: Missing required header for this request: x-amz-content-sha256
Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining
```

Comment: Can you paste you ~/.aws/config file without the credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your answers , The issue was with permission with the profile used , the credential must have access rights to both the S3 Buckets

Comment: This was my case.

Answer (score 5):

Check your region. This [error](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2112) is known to happen if your region is not set correctly.

Comment: Wow, that's weak.  Not your answer, but the behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I confirm it is an issue of setting a wrong region , However the question now is :

> How to know what it is the region of S3 ?

The answer is in the link of any asset hosted there .

So , assume one of your assets which is hosted under `bucket-1` has a link :

`https://s3.eu-central-2.amazonaws.com/bucket-1/asset.png`

This mean your REGION is **eu-central-2**

Alright , so, run :

```
aws configure
```

And change your region accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have set the following correctly:

- AWS credentials
- region
- permissions of the bucket is set to publicly accessible
- IAM policy of the bucket

And assuming you are using boto3 client,
then another thing that could be causing the problem is the signature version in the botocore.config.Config.

```
import boto3
from botocore import config

AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"
BOTO3_CLIENT_CONFIG = config.Config(
    region_name=AWS_REGION,
    signature_version="v4",
    retries={"max_attempts": 10, "mode": "standard"},
)
s3_client = boto3.client("s3", config=BOTO3_CLIENT_CONFIG)
result = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket="my-bucket-name", Prefix="", Delimiter="/")
```

Here the signature_version cannot be "v4". It should be "s3v4". Or the signature_version argument should be excluded altogether as by default it is "s3v4".

Answer (score 0):

I received this error in bash scripts without any sdk.

In my fix, I was missing to add `x-amz-content-sha256` and `x-amz-date` in my cURL request.

**Notably**

**x-amz-date**

required by AWS, must contain the timestamp of the request; the accepted format is quite flexible, I’m using ISO8601 basic format.
*Example: 20150915T124500Z*

**x-amz-content-sha256**

required by AWS, must be the SHA256 digest of the payload

The request will carry no payload (i.e. the body will be empty). This means that wherever a “payload hash” is required, we will provide an SHA256 hash of an empty string. And that is a constant value of e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855. This concerns the x-amz-content-sha256 header as well.

***Detailed explanation:*** https://czak.pl/2015/09/15/s3-rest-api-with-curl.html